# How to call a network in tf.keras.Sequential()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

If I use pytorch, I could use [index] to loop the layers:

```
layers = nn.ModuleList()
q = nn.ModuleList()
for _ in range(10):
        layers.append(attn)
        q.append(nn.Linear(dim1, dim2))
list = []
for index, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
        Q = q[index](inputTensor)
        list.append(layer(attn))
```

so when we use tensorflow, can we still use index like pytorch?

```
layers = tf.keras.Sequential()
q = tf.keras.Sequential()
for _ in range(10):
        layers.add(attn)
        q.add(Dense(dim2))
list = []
for index, layer in enumerate(layers):
        Q = layer[index](inputTensor)
        list.add(layer(att))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is possible:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128), 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) ])

for layer in model.layers:
        Q = layer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I slightly changed the qustion by adding another list to compare, so that I could get a better understanding. Was my approach valid?

Comment: @RhiannonYY yes, you can index, it's not a PyTorch or TensorFlow feature, it works with anything you can run in a `for loop`

Comment: @Muyide Ibukun Thanks! So we can use index to fetch a certain network in Sequential(), right?